# To check execution in DB

Tags: oracle, jdbc

is there a way to know that of the say 100 DDL and DML statement which i am executing through jdbc , is something stuck.
i need to find out for progress bar that in db sql statements are executing and are not hung, so that can inform to user.
Is there a way to find this out.

Comment: If you execute one by one, you will anyways know the status(timeouts can be done using [queryTimeOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getQueryTimeout%28%29)). If you wish to send all the `DDLs` and `DMLs` in batch, you can spawn multiple threads for it. But threads may not be a safe approach.

Comment: suppose some 3rd party DDL and DML are executing , then we can't figure out   whether it should have been finished by this time or not.. on the other hand if we can monitor something like block size change or some other change which suggests yes some activity is still going on, would be much beneficial

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of Oracle data dictionary views that you might use given the relatively vague requirements (what, exactly, is your definition of "hung", for example).

I'd probably start, though, with [`v$session`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm) assuming you can identify the `sid` and `serial#` of the particular session that you want to monitor (which may be aided by looking at the various columns in `v$session`).  `STATUS` will tell you whether the session is actively executing a SQL statement at that particular instant.  The `sql_id` will (generally) let you join to `v$sqlarea` or other views that tell you what statement is currently executing.  The `event` column will tell you what the session is waiting on (i.e. reading from disk, waiting on CPU, waiting to acquire a lock, etc.).

The `sql_id` from `v$session` will also let you join to `v$sqlstats` which periodically updates with things like the amount of logical I/O a particular SQL statement has generated which would let you see that the currently active statement is doing something (whether that something is useful or whether it will terminate in our lifetime would be much more difficult).

Depending on what the code is doing, there may be one or more rows in `v$session_longops` that you can use to track the progress of longer-running operations-- using this effectively, though, will require that the third-party code issues the sort of long-running SQL operations that Oracle can monitor automatically (i.e. table scans of tables that have a reasonable amount of data) or that the code is instrumented to use `v$session_longops` to track its own progress.

Depending on what version of Oracle you're using, you might also be able to [use the `v$sql_monitor` view to monitor SQL in real time](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/real-time-sql-monitoring-11gr1.php).